# how to reconnect to a docker logs --follow where the log file was deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logging

I have a docker container running in a small AWS instance with limited disk space. The logs were getting bigger, so I used the commands below to delete the evergrowing log files:

```
sudo -s -H
find /var -name "*json.log" | grep docker | xargs -r rm
journalctl --vacuum-size=50M
```

Now I want to see what's the behaviour of one of the running docker containers, but it claims the log file has disappeared (from the `rm` command above):

```
ubuntu@x-y-z:~$ docker logs --follow name_of_running_docker_1
error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: open /var/lib/docker/containers/d9562d25787aaf3af2a2bb7fd4bf00994f2fa1a4904979972adf817ea8fa57c3/d9562d25787aaf3af2a2bb7fd4bf00994f2fa1a4904979972adf817ea8fa57c3-json.log: no such file or directory
```

I would like to be able to see again what's going on in the running container, so I tried:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/docker/containers/d9562d25787aaf3af2a2bb7fd4bf00994f2fa1a4904979972adf817ea8fa57c3/d9562d25787aaf3af2a2bb7fd4bf00994f2fa1a4904979972adf817ea8fa57c3-json.log
```

And again `docker follow`, but while interacting with the software that should produce logs, I can see that nothing is happening.

Is there any way to rescue the printing into the log file again without killing (rebooting) the containers?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to rescue the printing into the log file again without killing (rebooting) the containers?

Yes, but it's more of a trick than a real solution. **You should never interact with `/var/lib/docker` data directly**. As per [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#choose-the-right-type-of-mount):

> part of the host filesystem [which] is managed by Docker (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/` on Linux). Non-Docker processes should not modify this part of the filesystem.

---

For this trick to work, you need to configure your [Docker Daemon to keep containers alive during downtime](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/#enable-live-restore) before first running our container. For example, by setting your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with:

```
{
  "live-restore": true
}
```

This requires Daemon restart such as `sudo systemctl restart docker`.

Then create a container and delete its `.log` file:

```
$ docker run --name myhttpd -d httpd:alpine
$ sudo rm $(docker inspect myhttpd -f '{{ .LogPath }}')

# Docker is not happy
$ docker logs myhttpd
error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: open /var/lib/docker/containers/xxx-json.log: no such file or directory
```

Restart Daemon (with live restore), this will cause Docker to somehow re-take management of our container and create our log file back. However, any logs generate before log file deletion are lost.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
$ docker logs myhttpd # works! and log file is created back
```

*Note: this is not a documented or official Docker feature, simply a behavior I observed with my own experimentations using Docker `19.03`. It may not work with other Docker versions*

*With live restore enabled, our container process keeps running even though Docker Daemon is stopped. On Docker daemon restart, it probably somehow try to re-read from the still alive process `stdout` and `stderr` and redirect output to our log file (hence re-creating it)*

Comment: I guess if live-restore wasn't set up, then we are stuck with an empty log. But good to know that this solves the issue.